# How to bind the height of an object to the height of an Element minus the height of another element.

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have my main page. I have my control. My control has a label and a grid.
I want to bind the height of my grid in my control to the height of my main page minus the label height. I'm not sure how to do this. If somebody could help or show my some documentation on how to do this that would be great.

Comment: That is not at all necessary. Just declare the RowDefinitions appropriately. Set `Height="Auto"` for the Label row, and no Height for the Grid row.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, you really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Handle `Loaded` event of your `Grid`. Code below changes `Width` to half of containing `Window`, you can do what ever you like using this approach.

```
    private void Grid_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grd = sender as Grid;
        DependencyObject parent = grd;
        while (!((parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent)) is Window)) ;

        if (parent == null) return;
        grd.Width = (parent as Window).ActualWidth / 2;            
    }
```